# How to load images in a local zip file in electron webviews?

Tags: javascript, electron

I can show an image inside a zip file in electron using the following code.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="zip_resources://images.zip/apple.jpg"/>
  <script>
    // You can also require other files to run in this process
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### renderer.js

```
protocol.registerBufferProtocol("zip_resources", async (request, callback) => {
  const urlExploded = request.url.split("/"); // [ 'zip_resources:', '', 'images.zip', 'apple.jpg' ]
  const zip = urlExploded[2]; // images.zip
  const fileName = urlExploded[3]; // apple.jpg
  const fileContents = await extractFileFromZip(zip, fileName);
  callback({ data: fileContents, mimeType: "image" });
});
```

As you can see, to make it work, I created a custom protocol `zip_resources://` and told electron how to load resources from this protocol by using `registerBufferProtocol`. But what if the `img` tag is in a webview? Like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <webview
      src="data:text/html,<img src='zip_resources://images.zip/apple.jpg'/>"
  />
  <script>
    // You can also require other files to run in this process
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make webview load this kind of resources correctly?

Comment: What do you mean "without extracting the zip file"? Don't you have to extract the file like you did in `registerBufferProtocol` to display it?

Comment: @pushkin I meant "without extracting the zip file **beforehand**", even before the app ran, in which case you could just use the `file://` protocol to fetch the image. However, I noticed that it was easily misunderstood and redundant. So I deleted relevant descriptions.